# In Corona SDK, how do you extract the x1, y1, x2, and y2 coordinates from a line display object?

Tags: corona-sdk

I used this command to create a line:

```
local myLine = display.newLine( 0,-110, 27,-35 )
```

How can I get the coordinates from `myLine`? I've looked [here](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/common-methods) and [here](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/common-properties) but the closest thing I could find is `myLine.x` and `myLine.y`, which appear to be `x1` and `y1` (not sure), but I can't figure out how to get `x2` and `y2`.

I want this information in order to detect if two lines intersect on the screen.

Comment: You just created the line and passed the coordinates in. How can you not have them afterward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Corona before but reading through the documentation I believe you can't easily retrieve these coordinates back from the generated display object. From what I read, `display.newLine` returns a [vector display object](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/vector-display-objects) to which you can `append` as many vertices as you want, but there's no way to access those values.

I guess you could use `line.contentBounds` to get back the size of the rectangle that encompasses the line, but this wouldn't tell you which diagonal to pick.

What I would suggest is to encapsulate this behavior in your own separate `Line` class (if that's possible in Corona) which stores the vertices, provides access to them, and generates the display object for you. Since I'm not familiar with Corona I'll use another language, but try to think of it as pseudocode.

I hope you can understand the general idea and can adapt it to some Corona *equivalent*. Let me know if there's something you don't understand:

```cs
class Line
{
     public Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
     {
         this.x1 = x1;
         this.y1 = y1;
         this.x2 = x2;
         this.y2 = y2;
     }

     public int x1, y1, x2, y2;

     public DisplayObject GetDisplayObject()
     {
         return display.newLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
     }

     public bool Intersects(Line other) 
     {
         // Line segment intersection algorithm
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution could be to add yourself the properties to your line

```
local line = display.newLine( x1,y1, x2,y2 )
line.x1 = x1
line.x2 = x2
line.y1 = y1
line.y2 = y2
```

then later you can grab `line.x2, line.y2`